# Get a Page from its Navigation Location String

Tags: c#, navigation, modal-dialog, maui

In MAUI Shell apps, my ViewModel makes use of GotoAsync to remain decoupled from the View. The VM project does not reference the UI project at all. In the phone number ViewModel, for example, I have code like the following:

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//person/edit/phonenumber", new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "phoneNumber", this }});
```

This works nicely. However, for my purposes, it makes sense for the phone number editor page to be modal. Now, of course, I could push the page to the modal navigation stack in my UI project, but I'd really like to do this from the ViewModel without referencing the UI.

Is there a way to take the navigation string "//person/edit/phonenumber" and get the type of page it refers to, so that I can create an instance on the modal navigation stack?

Comment: Where/how are you declaring your routes ?

Comment: Where possible, my routes are declared in XAML (in the Shell, for example). Where the types do not directly appear in the shell, I declare them using Routine.RegisterRoute in MauiProgram.cs (ie in the UI). Being experienced with WPF but very new to MAUI I hope that's right!

Comment: honestly i didn't quiet understand your final goal. i feel like there is a simpler approach.

Comment: @AJ. But when you use register route you can refer the type of the page, for example : Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(yourPage), typeof(yourPage)); and also, when you navigate with gotoAsync you can refer nameof(phoneNumberPage), what is your final goal? It's a little bit confused